# How can I Pop a Custom Dialog Box in a flexible In App Update?

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

I am trying to get In app updates using the android play core library (com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4). The documentation provided by google is as in the following link: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

As described in the **Start an Update** section, I am trying to call the API    *"appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult"* to start the update. In case of a flexible update, this pops up a default dialogue box for the user to choose between "Update" and "No Thanks". Is there a way for me to change this and pop up my own custom dialog?[image]

Comment: what do you want to do with custom dialog?

Comment: Just wanted to understand why you would like to change this dialog. As far as I can see, this is not possible. Cannot confirm this though yet.

Comment: I just want to change the "No Thanks" option to something like "Remind me Later" as the latter gives different meaning and also change the color schemes as well.

Comment: Please let me know, if you have any success on this.

Comment: Any updates on customising the dialog

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to use a custom dialog for this.

Or rather, there is no way to *not use* the Google Play dialog. You can add a custom UI before/after in your own app, but be careful about the overall user experience - you don't want to have too many dialogs.

The Google Play dialog has to appear as part of this process, as the actual update is handled by the Play app on the device.

Comment: Hey! Do you know is it possible to customize the text in the dialog?

Comment: Any update on customizing text, Can we do this?